# How Do I Know if a Comic Book Issue Is Part of a Series?

Tags: comics, dc, marvel

I'm still quite new to comics and, at this point, I'm just looking at the Marvel and the DC universes.  (I know there's a lot of publishers and all of them probably have their own rules, so we'll stick with the ones that are big where I live.)  And when I browse comics, like the list of ones being released [this coming Wednesday](http://ifanboy.com/comics/week/2012-03-07/) (3/7/2012), I see some specify a number in a sequence.  For instance, on this page, the *Thor Deviants Saga* specifies "5 of 5," but then I look at *Green Arrow* and it's just #7.  There's no "7 of 10" or possibly a "3 of 4" (which would mean #1 - #4 were the first story arc and a second one started at #5).

In some cases, like with the Thor series I mentioned, it's clear.  I know from the cover that if I buy this issue, I'm going to want the 4 before it.  With Green Arrow, I don't know if I need all 6 before it, or how long the series will go on.

How do I know if a particular issue is a one-off, the start of a story, or an unending story?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two types of comic books: mini-series and ongoing series. This is actually relatable to television mini-series (like "V") and long-running series (like "Star Trek: TNG"). So *[Thor: Deviants Saga](http://comicbookdb.com/title.php?ID=35091)* is a mini-series, meaning there are only 5 parts, and the series runs alongside and independent of the Thor ongoing series, called *[Mighty Thor](http://comicbookdb.com/title.php?ID=32873)* which is currently on #11 (and will be continued to be published until sales decline or etc). *[Green Arrow](http://comicbookdb.com/title.php?ID=34451)* #7, which does not state something like "7 of 12," indicates it is an ongoing series and has no set end point.

The best way to find out if a comic book is starting a newstory arc or is a good jumping on point is to read the summaries or investigate the covers. In the case of *Green Arrow* #7, I'd say that is a good jumping on point because the [summary](http://ifanboy.com/comics/green-arrow-7-2/) says

> Join new creative team Anne Nocenti and Harvey Tolibao as they chart
>   the next chapter in the life of Oliver Queen!

Summaries will also sometimes indicate **"Part 1 of xxx Storyarc!"** Covers will sometimes say this too, or they will say something like **"First issue in a bold new era!"** or **"New beginning starts here!"** to note that even though it is not a #1 issue, it is a jumping on point. The comic book companies know they have a daunting back catalogue that can be off-putting to new readers, so they really try to advertise the jumping on points. Another thing that Marvel specifically does, they publish **Point One issues**, which are intended to be jumping on points. So for instance, if you see *[Amazing Spider-Man](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=243168)* #679.1 or [*Thunderbolts* #163.1](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=234567) then that means that, hopefully, it's a standalone issue that is meant to be a jumping on point. This isn't always the case with Point One issues, but it is the intention.

So to sum up, "#3 of 5" means a series is a mini, and telling one complete story in five issues. #3 means it's the third issue of a series that will keep going until it gets canceled.

The best ways to tell if a comic is a good jumping on point are:

- If it's a #1 issue, either mini-series (#1 of 5) or ongoing (#1)
- If the summary declares it has a new creative team or starts a new storyarc
- If the cover itself boldly states it's a new direction, new beginning, new storyarc, etc
- If it is a Marvel Point One issue

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Brett has already mentioned you will sometimes find that a comic book will be listed as #xxx.1 which denotes that it is the first in a new arc, or at least notes a the first issue after a finished arc. Where #XXX is the number of the last issue. For example:

- **The Amazing Spider-man**, Vol 2, #678 Part 1: Schrodinger's catastrophe
- **The Amazing Spider-man**, Vol 2, #679 Part 2: A Date With Predestiny
- **The Amazing Spider-man**, Vol 2, #679.1 Who is in Lab 6?